Does Quran 35:41 mean the earth doesn’t move? Is “تَزُولَا” properly translated as “cease” or “move”?
Is it true that Quran 35:41 means that the earth doesnt move? I see some websites translating "تَزُولَا ۚ" as "cease" but can anyone tell me if this is a proper translation? Because as im reading tafsir i see that it means the heavens and earth dont move.

Rather than saying “question about heavens and earth “ , try summarising your whole question in one sentence for example Does Quran 35:41 mean the earth doesn’t move? Is “تَزُولَا” properly translated as “cease” or “move”?

It would have been helpful to know which tafsir you were using, but this is the verse you mention in Arabic:

۞ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ يُمْسِكُ ٱلسَّمَـٰوَٰتِ وَٱلْأَرْضَ أَن تَزُولَا ۚ وَلَئِن زَالَتَآ إِنْ أَمْسَكَهُمَا مِنْ أَحَدٍۢ مِّنۢ بَعْدِهِۦٓ ۚ إِنَّهُۥ كَانَ حَلِيمًا غَفُورًۭا

This is the Sahih International translation:

Indeed, Allāh holds the heavens and the earth, lest they cease. And if they should cease, no one could hold them [in place] after Him. Indeed, He is Forbearing1 and Forgiving.

This is the translation according to the Clear Quran, by Dr. Mustafa Khattab:

Indeed, Allah ˹alone˺ keeps the heavens and the earth from falling apart. If they were to fall apart, none but Him could hold them up. He is truly Most Forbearing, All-Forgiving.

The translation by Dr. Mustafa Khattab is more clear on what "cease" would mean, but if we go to the Tafsir of Ibn Kathir (reference) for this specific verse, we see him state the following about it:

Means, no one can make them (the heavens and the earth) stay and preserve them except Him. He is Ever Most Forbearing and Oft-Forgiving because He sees His servants disbelieving in Him and disobeying Him, yet He is patient and gives them time, He waits and does not hasten the punishment, and He conceals the faults of others and forgives them.

The rest of what he says is about the "إِنَّهُۥ كَانَ حَلِيمًا غَفُورًۭا" part of the Ayah, but you can see that it means that Allah holds them in place, and there is no one but Him who can do so.

so holding in place doesnt mean stationary?

Hey, I am sorry I didn't see this earlier, but you can imagine a screw holding a painting a up from falling. I know it's not perfect, but Allah doesn't mean stationary as we know it's moving (relative to an outside observer).

No holding in place doesn't necessitate for it to be stationary. It could be that Allah hold the sun and moon and earth within its range of motion not allowing it leave its orbit. For example, if you ever seen a massage gun, it vibrate, you can hold it up but it will still vibrate. Holding it up doesn't stop it from vibrating.
